# Change julia promt to include evalutation numbers

Tags: julia, prompt

When debugging or running julia code in REPL, I usually see error messages showing `... at ./REPL[161]:12 [inlined]...`. The number `161` means the `161-th` evaluation in REPL, I guess. So my question is could we show this number in julia's prompt, i.e. `julia [161]>` instead of `julia>`?

Comment: You could investigate [OhMyREPL](https://github.com/KristofferC/OhMyREPL.jl), [this Discourse post](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/changing-the-repl-prompt-from-startup-file/2151), and [TerminalExtensions](https://github.com/Keno/TerminalExtensions.jl). But the answer is basically no (at least not easily).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the advantages of Julia is its ultra flexibility. This is very easy in Julia 0.7 (nightly version).

```
julia> repl = Base.active_repl.interface.modes[1]
"Prompt(\"julia> \",...)"

julia> repl.prompt = () -> "julia[$(length(repl.hist.history) - repl.hist.start_idx + 1)] >"
#1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia[3] >

julia[3] >2
2

julia[4] >f = () -> error("e")
#3 (generic function with 1 method)

julia[5] >f()
ERROR: e
Stacktrace:
 [1] error at .\error.jl:33 [inlined]
 [2] (::getfield(, Symbol("##3#4")))() at .\REPL[4]:1
 [3] top-level scope
```

You just need to put the first 2 lines onto your `~/.juliarc` and enjoy~

Since there are several changes in the REPL after julia 0.7, these codes do not work in old versions.

EDIT: Well, actually there need a little bit more efforts to make it work in `.juliarc.jl`. Try this code:

```
atreplinit() do repl
    repl.interface = Base.REPL.setup_interface(repl)
    repl = Base.active_repl.interface.modes[1]
    repl.prompt = () -> "julia[$(length(repl.hist.history) - repl.hist.start_idx + 1)] >"
end
```

Comment: I would rename `repl` (where it represents `Prompt` type) to `base_mode` to not mix one name for 2 different meanings/types. (not only for didactic reasons)

Comment: Cool! Got any links to relevant documentation?

Comment: That's great, thanks! julia 0.7 release will come soon anyway.

Comment: @Liso Yes, thanks. I didn't consider the name when I wrote the code before dropping them to `.juliarc.jl`

Comment: @daycaster I learnt the REPL stuff in [this code](https://github.com/Keno/Cxx.jl/blob/master/src/CxxREPL/replpane.jl#L186) and how to show line number [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/2625#issuecomment-306342556)

Answer (score 2):

just to update to julia >v1.9, a [numbered prompt was added](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/46474)

add the following to your startup.jl

```
atreplinit() do repl
    try
        @eval using REPL
    catch e
        @warn "error while imporing REPL" e
    end
    if !isdefined(repl, :interface)
        repl.interface = REPL.setup_interface(repl)
    end
    REPL.numbered_prompt!(repl)
end
```